# How is the data chunked when using UploadFromStreamAsync and DownloadToStreamAsync when uploading to block blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I just started learning about Azure blob storage. I have come across various ways to upload and download the data. One thing that puzzles me to when to use what.

I am mainly interested in `PutBlockAsync` in conjunction with `PutBlockListAsync` and `UploadFromStreamAsync`.
As far as I understand when using `PutBlockAsync` it is up to the user to break the data into chunks and making sure each chunk is within the Azure block blob size limits. There is an id associated with each chunk that is uploaded. At the end, all the ids are committed.

When using UploadFromStreamAsync, how does this work? Who handles chunking the data and uploading it.

Why not convert the data into Stream and use `UploadFromStreamAsync` all the time and avoid two commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fiddler, and observe what happens when use `UploadFromStreamAsync`.

If the file is larger(more than 256MB), such as 500MB, the [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) and [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) api are called in the background(they are also called when use `PutBlockAsync` and `PutBlockListAsync` method)

If the file is small than 256MB, then it(`UploadFromStreamAsync`) will call the [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) api in the background.

I use `UploadFromStreamAsync` and uploading a file whose size is 600MB, then open the fidder.

Here are some findings from fidder:

1.The large file is broken into small size(4MB) one by one, and calls `Put Block` api in the background:

[image]

2.At the end, the `Put Block List` api will be called:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.